# Get distinct column values to an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Using below query I get the column values to an array. Now I want to get distinct column values from it.

```
DECLARE
@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',

SELECT 
@columns+=QUOTENAME(Question_no) + ','
FROM
marks_details  order by Question_no

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);
```

marks_details

```
Submission_id   Question_no
    200             1
    200             2
    300             2
    301             3
    302             3
```

The @columns should be [1,2,3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(Question_no) + ','
FROM (
  SELECT Question_no
  FROM marks_details
  GROUP BY Question_no
) X
ORDER BY Question_no;

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
select @columns = string_agg( question_no, ',') within group (order by question_no)
from (select distinct question_no
      from marks_details
     ) md;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed19106de07976b2547a68ec8d41eeaa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @DaleK . . . Yes.